# How to override a method in java from kotlin where a param is of type SomeType<*>? but need to assign to SomeType<String>?

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

```
class SomeClass: ThirdPartyBaseClass {
    private var someValue: AnotherType<String>? = null

    override fun initialize(param1: AType?, param2: AnotherType<*>?) {
        this.someValue = param2
    }
}
```

When I `override` initialize method from `ThirdPartyBaseClass`, Android Studio autocomplete adds the signature above. `AnotherType` is basically a generic type (from the 3rd part lib) and 'T' needs to be 'String' for me to use it. The problem is that I can't assign `param2` to `someValue` because I get the error:

> `type mismatch: required AnotherType<String>? found: AnotherType<*>?.`

What is the proper way to fix this?

Comment: did you try  : this.somevalue = param2 as String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use type cast to achieve this. Try:

```
override fun initialize(param1: AType?, param2: AnotherType<*>?) {
    this.someValue = param2 as AnotherType<String>?
}
```

Comment: @u84six, Did you try this?

Comment: When I do that, I get an 'unchecked cast' warning. Seems like no matter what I try, there's a different warning or error. It's like whack-a-mole. Seems to work smoothly with non generics. It's generics where I'm whacking moles as I code.

Comment: I'm new to Kotlin and has been a bit of a pain working with Java libs so far.

Comment: It's not a problem since it's a nullable value. Kotlin handle this. Check this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html

Comment: So it's just a warning that we're supposed to ignore?

Comment: Yes, It's a warning

Comment: After reading the docs, I suppose I can put @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") to suppress the warning since I can't edit the java lib. Seems like a kludgy solution. But I'll give you the answer for the cast.

Comment: If you don't want to bother about the warning then Suppress it. :)